# Define function based on asymptotes and intercept

Tags: logarithms

I'm looking for a function with the following characteristics:

- Vertical asymptote at $0$ (i.e. function never touches negative $x$-values)
- Horizontal asymptote at $7$ (i.e. function never results in $y$-values larger than $7$)
- $x$-intercept at $0.25$ (i.e. function crosses $x$-axis at $(0.25,0)$)

I tried working with a log-function (e.g. $y=\ln(x+0.75)$). This generally helped to achieve the intercept, but I still couldn't make the asymptotes work. Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: function crosses x-axis at (0,0.25) ??

How can a function cross the x-axis above the x axis on the horizontal asymptote? Did you mean (0.25,0)?

Comment: Typo, sorry. Intercept at (0.25,0)

Comment: Logarithms never have upper bounds, so that will never work.
Also, a horizontal asymptote does not mean that x values cannot be higher than 7.
y=1/x has horizontal and vertical asymptotes, yet the value of a function can be higher than the horizontal asymptote.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a log-function. It just has a shape very close to what I'm looking for so that why I started with it. Also, there is no restriction with respect to x-values, you are correct. I just want that even with an x-value of 1,000, the y-value never ends up above the asymptote of 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function:

$$ y = \begin{cases} 
          undefined & x\leq 0 \\
          7(1-\frac{1}{4x}) &  x > 0 
       \end{cases}
$$

This statisfies your requirements.

A logarithmic function is growing continuously and will never work. It has no upper bound.

A few more points:

- A horizontal asymptote does not mean that y values cannot be higher than the value of the asymptote.
- A vertical asymptote does not mean that x values cannot be lower than the value of the asymptote.

So, according to that, the function below also satisfies your requirements:
$$y = 7(1-\frac{1}{4x})$$

[image: y = 7(1-1/(4x))]

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That is what I was looking for